# Sqlite Get x rows, then next x rows

Tags: android, sql

Im developing android app, which use SQLite database.

I have **ListView** which uses data from Database to show a list (see picture).

The picture is decoded in Base64 String and stored in Database. My problem is this Log:

```
10-19 16:51:36.612: W/CursorWindow(15151): Window is full: 
requested allocation 136877 bytes, free space 78836 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
```

It skypes a lot of Frames, because the read time grows.
This is because i read always x+10 rows. 
1st, it reads 10 rows, then 20, then 30 and go on...

**The solution, what i want to use is, get rows from 0-10, 11 - 20, 21 - 30 and so on. How to achieve this? I just need the Sql query.**

**EDIT:** my query

```
String columns[] = {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_RATING, KEY_CUISINE, KEY_IMAGE};
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_RECIPES, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME, lim);
```

[image: ListView]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the rawQuery method, and specify the limit keyword.

e.g.:

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable limit 10" <-- get the 1st 10 rows
"SELECT * FROM myTable limit 10, 20" <-- get the 2nd 10 rows between 10 and 20, etc
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Also, you can use query() where you set on the limit parameter a string like this "10, 20". :)

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM myTable limit 10, 20"`
this will give to 20 rows from 11 to 30.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer above and the result was:

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable limit 10" <-- Got the first 10 rows
"SELECT * FROM myTable limit 10, 20" <-- Got the first 20 rows !
```

So the answer above did not work for me, what worked for me was this:

This is my table:

[image: table]

To get the **first 10**:

```
select * from quran_text where sura = 2 limit 0, 10
```

[image: first10]

**Second 10:**

```
select * from quran_text where sura = 2 limit 10, 10
```

[image: second10]

**Third 10:**

```
select * from quran_text where sura = 2 limit 20, 10
```

[image: third10]

in the picture it shows only 5 record cuz of space, but it gets the right result.

so to make it as pattern:

to get it for first 10 here X = 1;

creating query in java:

```
String query = "select * from quran_text where sura = 2 limit "+((X-1)*10)+", 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the syntax:

```
LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset;
```

versus

```
LIMIT offset, row_count;
```

Order of arguments is not the same

Answer (score 0):

```
item_to_start_from = 0
num_items_to_get = 20
with sql_connection:
    sql_statement = f"""SELECT * FROM TABLE 
                        LIMIT {item_to_start_from},{num_items_to_get}"""
    rows = sql_connection.execute(sql_statement)
    # iterable rows
```

Comment: Note that answers that contain only code are generally considered as poor quality. Consider adding some explanation of what the code is doing.