# Load more SQLite data in Fragment's ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, scroll

I'm trying to implement the following:

> In the tab "List" (Fragment) of the activity, I need to show a custom ListView with some "Topics" saved in the SQLite local DB. I want to show, like, 10 of them and give the user the chance to scroll down and auto-add other "Topics" if they are present.

I've tried to help myself with shontauro's [LoadMore project](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore) but I can't figure out what's the problem.

**ListFragment**

```
    public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Topic> values;
    private static int offset = 0;
    private static int increment = 10;
    ArrayList<Topic> adapter;
    public boolean isLoading = false;
    TopicListView postList;
    public Handler mHandler;
    CustomAdapter cAdapter;
    View ftView;
    boolean alreadyCreated = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
        values = activity.getDatasource().getAllTopics();
        Collections.reverse(values);

        adapter = new ArrayList<Topic>(values);
        cAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getContext(), adapter);

        postList = new TopicListView(getContext());
        postList = (TopicListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_list);

        postList.setAdapter(cAdapter);
        postList.setOnLoadMoreListener(new TopicListView.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            public void onLoadMore() {
                new LoadDataTask().execute();
            }
        });

        postList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Topic pickedTopic = null;
                pickedTopic = (Topic) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                StringBuilder topic = new StringBuilder();
                topic.append("Topic: ").append(pickedTopic.getTopic_type()).append("\n");
                topic.append("Estimated time: ").append(pickedTopic.getEstimatedTime()).append("\n");
                topic.append("Severity: ").append(pickedTopic.getSeverity()).append("\n");
                topic.append("Message: ").append(pickedTopic.getMessage()).append("\n");
                builder.setMessage("Post: \n\n" + topic.toString())
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (isCancelled()) {
                return null;
            }

            // Should I do something here?

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // notify the adapter that the data have been changed
            ((BaseAdapter) cAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Call onLoadMoreComplete when the LoadMore task, has finished
            ((TopicListView) postList).onLoadMoreComplete();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // Notify the loading more operation has finished
            ((TopicListView) postList).onLoadMoreComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

**TopicDataSource**

```
/**
 *  TopicsDataSource class contains all data related to the SQLite database.
 *
 */
public class TopicsDataSource {

    /**
     *  Database fields
     */
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns =
            {
                    DBHelper.ID,
                    DBHelper.ID_MONGO,
                    DBHelper.TOPIC_TYPE,
                    DBHelper.ESTIMATED_TIME,
                    DBHelper.SEVERITY,
                    DBHelper.MESSAGE
            };

    /**
     *  Constructor.
     *  @param context app's context
     */
    public TopicsDataSource(Context context) { dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);}

    /**
     * The method opens the db.
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void open() throws SQLException  { database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); }

    /**
     * The method closes the db.
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    /**
     * The function returns a Topic to be created.
     * @param id_mongo      mongoDB's primary key
     * @param topic_type    type of the topic
     * @param estimatedTime estimated time of the topic
     * @param severity      severity of the topic
     * @param message       message of the topic
     * @return  the created topic
     */
    public Topic createTopic(String id_mongo, String topic_type, int estimatedTime, int severity, String message)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.ID_MONGO, topic_type);
        values.put(DBHelper.TOPIC_TYPE, topic_type);
        values.put(DBHelper.ESTIMATED_TIME, estimatedTime);
        values.put(DBHelper.SEVERITY, severity);
        values.put(DBHelper.MESSAGE, message);
        values.put(DBHelper.CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        long insertId = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query( DBHelper.TABLE,
                allColumns,
                DBHelper.ID + " = " + insertId,
                null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Topic newTopic = cursorToName(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newTopic;
    }

    /**
     *  The functions returns the timestamp.
     *  @return the current time timestamp
     */
    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    /**
     *  The method deletes a topic from the database.
     *  @param topic to be deleted
     */
    public void deleteTopic(Topic topic)
    {
        long id = topic.getId();
        System.out.println("User deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, DBHelper.ID + " = '" + id + "'", null);
    }

    /**
     *  The function returns all the data of the database.
     *  @return list of all the Topics
     */
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics()
    {
        List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<Topic>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Topic topic = cursorToName(cursor);
            topics.add(topic);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return topics;
    }

    /**
     *  The function returns the Topic pointed by the cursor.
     *  @param cursor   cursor
     *  @return pointed Topic
     */
    private Topic cursorToName(Cursor cursor)
    {
        Topic user = new Topic();
        user.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        user.setId_Mongo(cursor.getString(1));
        user.setTopic_type(cursor.getString(2));
        user.setEstimatedTime(cursor.getInt(3));
        user.setSeverity(cursor.getInt(4));
        user.setMessage(cursor.getString(5));
        return user;
    }
}
```

**TopicListView**

```
        public class TopicListView extends ListView implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

        /**
         * Listener that will receive notifications every time the list scrolls.
         */
        private OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;

        /**
         * Reader for the XML file for creating the UI layout.
         */
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        /**
         *  Footer View
         */
        private RelativeLayout mFooterView;

        /**
         *  Progress bar
         */
        private ProgressBar mProgressBarLoadMore;

        /**
         *  Listener to process load more items when user reaches the end of the list.
         */
        private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

        /**
         *  Boolean To know if the list is loading more items.
         */
        private boolean mIsLoadingMore = false;

        /**
         *  State of the scroll.
         */
        private int mCurrentScrollState;

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         * @param context app'scontext
         */
        public TopicListView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         *  @param context app's context
         *  @param attrs attributes
         */
        public TopicListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
        }

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         *  @param context app's context
         *  @param attrs attributes
         *  @param defStyle style definition
         */
        public TopicListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }

        /**
         *  The method initialize all the UI components.
         *  @param context  app's context
         */
        private void init(Context context) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mFooterView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.progress_layout, this, false);
            mProgressBarLoadMore = (ProgressBar) mFooterView
                    .findViewById(R.id.load_more_progressBar);
            addFooterView(mFooterView);
            super.setOnScrollListener(this);
        }

        /**
         *  The method sets the adapter.
         */
        @Override
        public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        /**
         * The method sets the listener that will receive notifications every time the list
         * scrolls.
         * @param l the scroll listener
         */
        @Override
        public void setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener l) {
            mOnScrollListener = l;
        }

        /**
         * The method registers a callback to be invoked when this list reaches the end (last
         * item be visible).
         * @param onLoadMoreListener    The callback to run.
         */
        public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
            mOnLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
        }

        /**
         *  The method sets what to do in case of scrolling the list.
         *  @param view             current view
         *  @param firstVisibleItem first item of the list
         *  @param visibleItemCount number of visible items of the list
         *  @param totalItemCount   number of items
         */
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
                mOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem,
                        visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
            }

            if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                if (visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
                    mProgressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return;
                }

                boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;

                if (!mIsLoadingMore && loadMore
                        && mCurrentScrollState != SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    mProgressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mIsLoadingMore = true;
                    onLoadMore();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         *  The method sets what to do in case of a change in ste scroll status.
         *  @param view             current view
         *  @param scrollState      status of the scrolling
         */
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if ( scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ) { view.invalidateViews(); }
            mCurrentScrollState = scrollState;
            if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
                mOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
            }
        }

        /**
         *  The method invokes onLoadMore.
         */
        public void onLoadMore() {
            if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
            }
        }

        /**
         * The method notifies the 'loading more' operation has finished.
         */
        public void onLoadMoreComplete() {
            mIsLoadingMore = false;
            mProgressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        /**
         * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when list reaches the
         * last item (the user load more items in the list)
         */
        public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
            /**
             * Called when the list reaches the last item (the last item is visible
             * to the user)
             */
            public void onLoadMore();
        }
    }

**Topic**

        public class Topic {

        /**
         *  Attributes
         */
        private long    id;
        private String  id_mongo;
        private String topic_type;
        private int estimatedTime;
        private int severity;
        private String message;

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         */
        public Topic() {}

        /**
         *  Constructor.
         *  @param id_Mongo      mongoDB's primary key
         *  @param topic_type    type of the topic
         *  @param estimatedTime estimated time of the topic
         *  @param severity      severity of the topic
         *  @param message       message of the topic
         */
        public Topic(String id_Mongo, String topic_type, int estimatedTime, int severity, String message) {
            this.id_mongo = id_Mongo;
            this.topic_type = topic_type;
            this.estimatedTime = estimatedTime;
            this.severity = severity;
            this.message = message;
        }

        /**
         * Get {@see #id}.
         * @return  SQLite's primary key of the topic
         */
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        /**
         * Set {@see #id}.
         */
        public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

        /**
         * Get {@see #id_mongo}.
         * @return  mongoDB's primary key of the topic
         */
        public String getId_Mongo() {
            return id_mongo;
        }

        /**
         * Set {@see #id_mongo}.
         */
        public void setId_Mongo(String id_mongo) { this.id_mongo = id_mongo; }

        /**
         * Get {@see #topic_type}.
         * @return  type of the topic
         */
        public String getTopic_type() {
            return topic_type;
        }

        /**
         * Set {@see #topic_type}.
         */
        public void setTopic_type(String topic_type) {
            this.topic_type = topic_type;
        }

        /**
         * Get {@see #estimatedTime}.
         * @return  estimated amount of time of the topic to be worked
         */
        public int getEstimatedTime() {
            return estimatedTime;
        }

        /**
         * Set {@see #estimatedTime}.
         */
        public void setEstimatedTime(int estimatedTime) {
            this.estimatedTime = estimatedTime;
        }

        /**
         * Get {@see #severity}.
         * @return  severity of the topic
         */
        public int getSeverity() {
            return severity;
        }

        /**
         * Set {@see #severity}.
         */
        public void setSeverity(int severity) {
            this.severity = severity;
        }

        /**
         * Get {@see #message}.
         * @return  message of the topic
         */
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        /**
         * Set {@see #message}.
         */
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
       }
```

**List_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Topic type: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/estimatedTime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topic_type"
        android:text="Estimated Time: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/severity"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topic_type"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/estimatedTime"
        android:text="Severity: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topic_type"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/severity"
        android:text="Click for more info..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I am missing?

Comment: @pskink could you provide an example too?

Comment: @pskink how can I integrate the DAO with my TopicDataSource?

Comment: @pskink but that means rewriting all the Database class according to it, right? If so, there's a way to integrate what I have done with it?

Comment: But in the context of my application, whose part of the code is here, would change a lot, @pskink. That is why I am asking for an integration more than semplifying now

Comment: "It's your code" is not a helpful comment, but thanks anyway. @pskink

Comment: @pskink I'm damning myself for doing it. I'd need some help with the ViewHolder. How should I define it?

Comment: check this ans it may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451888/sqlite-get-x-rows-then-next-x-rows